# Python statsmodels doesn't seem to perform regularized negative binomial regression properly

Tags: python, statsmodels

I'm trying to fit a negative binomial regression using statsmodels.

HEre's my code:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
model = sm.NegativeBinomial
mod_nbin = model(Y, X)
res = mod_nbin.fit(disp=False, maxiter = 200)
res_nbin2 = mod_nbin.fit_regularized(start_params=res.params, alpha=10)
```

However, when I look at the results:

```
print res_nbin2.summary()
```

I see the following:

```
....

x45           -0.1876      0.024     -7.708      0.000        -0.235    -0.140
alpha          0.4742      0.011     41.510      0.000         0.452     0.497
```

So somehow, statsmodels is fitting the alpha value instead of using the one I specified. Any suggestions about how I can fix this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: bad naming, there are two different alpha. The alpha in `fit_regularized` is the penalization parameter. The alpha in the summary is the shape parameter of the NegativeBinomial. The penalization parameter will be renamed to an English name instead of a Greek letter.

Comment: Thanks!  So what exactly is alpha in the .summary()?  It should be r, the predefined number of failures that has occurred, right?  X~NegativeBinomial(r;p)

Comment: The parameterization differs between the `nb1` and `nb2` versions. `alpha=0` is the Poisson special case. `alpha` has the interpretation of a dispersion parameter with overdispersion compared to Poisson if `alpha>0`.

Comment: Ok. I think I see.  I should probably be using sm.GLM(family = NegativeBinomial), because I want to constrain my dispersion parameter to be 1?  But I can't seem to be able to call the regularized_fit()  method with the GLM.

Comment: As far as I can see `alpha=1` is `loglike_method='geometric'` which is the 3rd version of NegativeBinomial. Currently, `fit_regularized` is only available for `discrete_model`. Work has started to extend it to other models, but won't be finished very soon.